# NSDate value is always returned in my time zone

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

TL/DR: I need an `NSDate` representing `1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000` specifically. Using `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0]` returns the date adjusted for my time zone. I can't figure out how to fix this.

I am attempting to write an Objective-C iOS test that revolves around `NSDates`. The trouble is, any `NSDate` object I try to create, whether it's straight, or using `NSDateFormatter` or `[NSDateComponents dateFromComponents]`, will always seem to be adjusted for my Mac's current time zone. That is, tests will use the timezone-adjusted value of the NSDate, and it will also appear that way in the Xcode debugger. However, if I explicitly set the time zone to GMT in `NSDateComponents` or `NSDateFormatter`, when I check the value in the console using `po`, it will return the date/time in GMT like I set.

For instance, `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0]` returns an NSDate with the date `1969-12-31 19:00:00 -0500`. `[NSDate date]` returns the current date and time, but per my time zone: `2015-03-03 05:49:32 -0500`. I can't figure out for the life of me why I can't simply get `1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000` as an NSDate.

Is there something I'm missing? Can anyone help me out with this?

Thank you!

EDIT: Here's my attempt at using `NSDateComponents`:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                            initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [components setYear:1970];
    [components setMonth:1];
    [components setDay:1];
    [components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    NSDate *componentDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

`componentDate` displays properly in the console (when I type `po componentDate`), but displays in the debug window as being timezone-adjusted. Also, this timezone-adjusted value is what's being used in my tests, so it has a definite impact on my ability to write reliable tests.

Comment: That's because your screwy debugger is choosing to represent the date in local time zone.  `po` shows you what's really in the NSDate.

Comment: @HotLicks If it weren't affecting my test results, I'd be fine with that explanation. But the NSDate object itself is timezone-adjusted; it's not just how it's presented.

Comment: The NSDate object should not be timezone-adjusted.  The real time it contains is what you see if you NSLog it or do `po` on it.

Comment: I have seen (though not in years) situations where the timezone in the NSDate is set to other than UTC.  (Apparently there is an archaic timezone field in there.)  But it shouldn't affect how a NSDate prints with NSDateFormatter.  (Do you have an old development environment?  iOS or OSX?)

Comment: "Using `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0]` returns the date adjusted for my time zone." No it doesn't. It doesn't adjust `NSDate` at all. `NSDate` does not have a timezone; it reflects a point in time. How that instant in time is displayed is a function of `NSDateFormatter` (which _does_ understand the concept of timezones). So set your formatter's `timeZone` to `[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]` and it will appear in UTC format. Don't worry about what the debugger shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0]` represents the date you're asking for. It is the conversion of that `NSDate` to a string that involves your time zone.

---

As humans, we have many ways to represent an instant in time. For example, “January 1, 2001 00:00:00 GMT” represents a particular instant in time. Another name for the same instant is “December 31, 2000 18:00:00 America/Chicago”. A third name for the same instant is “January 1, 2001 03:00:00 Europe/Moscow”. All these names (strings), and many more, represent the same instant in time. As humans, we recognize that all of these labels represent the same instant in time.

An `NSDate` represents an instant in time in a completely different way: an `NSDate` stores an offset, in seconds, relative to a one predetermined reference instant. An `NSDate` doesn't store any time zone information. It stores just one double-precision number. For every instant in time, there is just one `NSDate` that represents it.<sup>1</sup>

Note the difference between human representations and `NSDate` representations: an instant has many human representations, but only one `NSDate` representation.

When you print a date using `%@` in `NSLog`, or using `po` in the debugger, it sends the `description` message to the date. The job of the `description` method is to produce some human representation for the unique instant represented by the `NSDate`. But there are many possible human representations, and the `description` method has to use just one. The implementors of the method decided to use the representation based on your local time zone.

If you don't like the use of the local time zone, don't use `description` (directly or indirectly). Create an `NSDateFormatter`, set its `timeZone`, set its other properties as desired, and use it to format your dates. You've already noted that this works. It is a correct solution to your problem.

If you want, you can add a category to `NSDate` defining a `gmtDescription` method that returns a representation of the date in GMT:

```
@interface NSDate (Argus9)
- (NSString *)gmtDescription;
@end

@implementation NSDate (Argus9)

- (NSString *)gmtDescription {
    static NSDateFormatter *df;
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        df.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
        df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    });
    return [df stringFromDate:self];
}

@end
```

---

Footnote 1. This is not quite true, because `double` has two zeros: +0 and -0. Both represent the same instant in time (the reference instant itself). Also, since `NSDate` stores its offset as a `double`, and there are a finite number of doubles, it cannot represent every instant in time uniquely. Many instants in time map to the same `double` value.

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough explanation. I'm still a bit new to Objective-C, so this is just another thing for me to try to wrap my head around, but your description helps a lot. And as it turns out, the method I'm trying to test does use an `NSDateFormatter`, but had no timezone set, so I'm guessing it used my Mac's system time zone during testing. Something for me to be conscious of from here on out!

Anyway, thanks again, I appreciate it!